# Cross-compile FreeBSD package as unprivileged user

Tags: freebsd, arm, cross-compilation

My goal is to cross-compile binaries from an amd64 FreeBSD host to an armv6 RaspberryPi FreeBSD target.

The problem I am running into is I am required to be root in order to `make install`, where my command would be `make PREFIX=/home/arm/install_dir NO_PKG_REGISTER=1 install`.  Even better would be to use `make package` for easier transfer to the target.

The issue is, while I *am* the sole administrator of the system and *do* have root capabilities, I would like to ensure I do not compromise the host system with an erroneous `make install` (such as one where I omit `PREFIX=` or `NO_PKG_REGISTER=1`).

As a precautionary measure, I do all the building as a separate user `arm` to help prevent me from unwittingly installing arm binaries on my host. In addition, this user has its own copy of the FreeBSD source and ports tree located separate from `/usr/src` and `/usr/ports`.

Is there a way for `make` to create a package without having root access?

Or can I have confidence that `PREFIX` and `NO_PKG_REGISTER` or `make package` will prevent my host from being polluted with inappropriate binaries?

EDIT: According to http://forums.freebsd.org/showpost.php?p=1518&postcount=7, the PREFIX approach is no good...hrm.  Did I mean DESTDIR instead?

Comment: That depends in part of the package's Makefile writer setting stuff up for installing at a place which isn't the final one. Perhaps creating a chroot for cross-builds with all the required pieces hard linked/mounted in?

Comment: Chroot or jail?  I'm relatively new to FreeBSD, so both of them will be a new endeavor, but I'd love to start with the most appropriate one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crosscompile of ports is not a supported configuration.
Same goes with building packages as unprivileged user.

It may work, but sometimes it does not.

I think setting up a chroot is a good idea, as it prevents you from accidently installing ARM binaries on your host system. a jail would also work, but is not necessary.