# Cross compile ports freebsd 11

Tags: freebsd, raspberry-pi, cross-compilation, bsd-ports

I want to make cross compile environment for raspberrypi. Now I have VM with qemu-arm based cross compilation environment (based on [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406033209/http://www.cruwe.de/blog/2014/02/18/compiling-freebsd-ports-for-raspberry/) article), and it is VERY SLOW.

I think that native i386 compiler can make executables for diffent arch, it needs only toolchain and properly configured make.conf, but I can be wrong.

Maybe someone know how to configure system for cross-building?

- Host System: freebsd 11 on vm i386
- Target: freebsd 11 armv6hf

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

There is already a cross compiler available for  FreeBSD 11.

You can try the gnatcross-aarch64 port on a i386 or amd64 host.

you may want to compile all the gnatcross bits from ports. There are two items which can be install using pkg. Just do "pkg search gnatcross" it will list them.

There might be a problem using FreeBSD 11 since it is not available for Raspberry PI 3. You will probably need to modify the gnatcross-* kits to use FreeBSD 12 files. I fiddled around and spiked the distfiles cache with the needed v12 files (base.txz). I changed the name of the ports I used. I shortened the names to gx-* instead of gnatcross-*

The gnatcross claim to fame is that it includes the Ada compiler.

There are various tips on creating a cross compiler in the FreeBSD environment. You can try [this one](http://allskyee.blogspot.no/2014/02/freebsd-10-ports-cross-compile-amd64-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've a VPS and I'm using it with poudriere (see [here](http://pkg.uzsolt.hu/)). I think this is the most simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I know that option. What I want is to make compilation without qemu. I've made _XDEV_ environment for _armv6hf_. Inside it i have _cc_ compiler with needed target and libraries. But when it comes to building _configure_ script cannot pass, because host cannot run arm-executables.

Comment: Do you know these: https://wiki.freebsd.org/QemuUserModeHowTo http://marcelog.github.io/articles/cross_freebsd_compiler_in_linux.html http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64078/cross-compile-freebsd-package-as-unprivileged-user? I've tried it without qemu but I failed and the poudriere with jails (and with qemu) was the simpliest solution for me - I didn't have time to find the problem.